# Flag Summary page takes a long time to load and/or shows the error page

Tags: support, status-completed, flag-history

When going to your flag summary, it takes a long time for the page to load. Sometimes it displays an *"Oops! Something Bad Happened!"* error page. Multiple people in the Tavern have said they're experiencing this problem.

Did someone break something?

Comment: Maybe too many people were complaining about declined flags so they decided to take that page down?

Comment: This seems to be generically-flag related, as several moderators have reported the flag queue page(s) erroring/ taking a while to load over the last few days as well.

Comment: A bunch of people in SOCVR have been noticing the same thing, too.

Comment: Can you try it again and let me know if it's loading now?

Comment: @bluefeet it's loading and it's fast again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Nick, this should be working again.  He did some performance tuning on it.

Comment: I still find it slower than usual (like 3 times slower), but it's working now.